# Swift - static member animate cannot be used on instance of type uiview

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the pod [EasyAnimate](https://cocoapods.org/pods/EasyAnimation) and I'm trying to do something very simple but I get this error:

> static member animate cannot be used on instance of type uiview

I'm using this code inside a closure that detects when an API request is completed. And that is inside the viewDidLoad function, which is inside my ViewController. I have removed irrelevant code to make it easy to read.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import EasyAnimation

class WeatherVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    //Launchscreen Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var launchScreenImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var launchScreenLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var launchScreenBG: UIView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        currentWeather = CurrentWeather()
        currentWeather.downloadWeatherDetails {
            self.downloadForecastData {
                self.updateMainUI()

                // Start animation from launch screen
                launchScreenBG.animate(duration: 2.0, animations: { <<<ERROR HERE
                    self.view.layer.position.x = 200.0
                })
            }

        }

    }


}
```

I thought this .animate function works on all UIViews, but I'm not sure what the issue is. It doesn't seem to care that it's inside a closure, and it doesn't seem to matter if I add `self.` before the UILabel name.

I can see that this pod allows animations for classes. But how do I animate an `IBOutlet`?

Any ideas what's going on here? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: How do you want the animation on launchScreenBG to look like?

Comment: At the moment I'm just testing *any* animations just to get it to work. Ideally it will change the height and move a few other IBOutlets x/y positioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static method can only be called on the class it is implemented on:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: { 
   //Do something with launchScreenBG here. For example:
   self.launchScreenBG.alpha = 0.0
})
```

This method essentially animates all view updates (transparency in this case) that are provided in the block.

Comment: Thanks for your response @ZeMoon. But how can the animation method differentiate which IBOutlet to conduct the animation on?

Comment: @Armin Have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your update! I have implemented the code and it definitely helped! however I am receiving a new error now: "Argument labels '(duration:, animations:)' do not match any available overloads"

Comment: The issue is that it's not "duration:" it's "withDuration:"